# When will OpenCL 1.2 for NVIDIA hardware be available?

Tags: cuda, opencl

I would have asked this question on the NVIDIA developer forum but since it's still down maybe someone here can tell me something.

Does anybody know if there is already OpenCL 1.2 support in NVIDIAs driver? If not, is it coming soon?

I don't have a GeForce 600 series card to check myself. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units#GeForce_600_Series) there are already some cards that could support it though.

It somewhat seems like NVIDIA does not mention OpenCL a whole lot anymore and just focuses on CUDA C/C++ (see [StreamComputing.eu](http://www.streamcomputing.eu/blog/2012-09-10/nvidias-industry-leading-support-for-opencl/)). I guess it makes sense to them but I would like to see some more OpenCL love.

Thanks

Comment: "but I would like to see some more OpenCL love." Then endorse AMD/Intel/Altera/etc.

Answer (score 8):

NVidia's latest SDK (v4.2.9) does not support OpenCL 1.2 with regard to the header files or library it provides. I considered this might just be the SDK itself: as you point out, the GeForce 600 series appears to support it in hardware. Unfortunately I don't own any 600 series card, but OpenCL64.dll supplied with the latest drivers (v306.23) does not export OpenCL 1.2 symbols. Further, I can find no trace of the new symbols (such as "clLinkProgram") as strings in the driver package. Although this does not rule out the possibility of bootstrapping 1.2 functionality in the driver via an ICD Loader, there is no evidence that there is an 1.2 implementation there, and this would be undocumented and unsupported.

As to when OpenCL 1.2 will be officially supported by NVidia, unfortunately I don't know the answer to this, and would be equally keen to find out.

In the mean-time you might consider an alternative OpenCL 1.2 implementation for development; for example the [Intel SDK 2013 Beta](http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk-2013) (Intel CPU) or [AMD APP SDK v2.7](http://developer.amd.com/tools/hc/AMDAPPSDK/downloads/Pages/default.aspx) (AMD CPU or AMD/ATI GPU).

An aside, but personally I am considering switching from NVidia GPUs to ATI for production purposes, partly based on AMD's investment in OpenCL and also arguments comparing "bang for buck" between NVidia and the latest AMD cards: [NVIDIA vs AMD: GPGPU performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638324/nvidia-vs-amd-gpgpu-performance)

Comment: What about now? I can't find any information about the Nvidia OpenCL 1.2 support...

Comment: I just checked NVidias 310.14 driver for my GeForce 560 GTX (Linux amd64), and still `clReleaseDevice` (which is an OpenCL 1.2 function) is undefined. So I guess / hope NVidia's libOpenCL.so is at least OpenCL 1.1 compatible.

Comment: I cannot comment from where - but I have reliably heard that nvidia does NOT intend to support OpenCL 1.2. They want to push people to adopt CUDA and therefore create vendor lock-in.

Answer (score 6):

The NVIDIA hotfix driver `version 350.05` (April 2015) adds support for [OpenCL 1.2](http://anandtech.com/show/9139/nvidia-posts-35005-hotfix-driver-fixes-games-adds-opencl-12-support).

With the `350.12` (also April 2015) release, NVidia has [clarified the situation](http://anandtech.com/show/9155/nvidia-releases-35012-game-ready-whql-drivers):

> With this driver release NVIDIA has also posted a bit more information on their OpenCL 1.2 driver. The driver has not yet passed OpenCL conformance testing over at Khronos, but it is expected to do so. OpenCL 1.2 functionality will only be available on Kepler and Maxwell GPUs, with Fermi getting left behind.

Comment: It appears it supports OpenCL 1.2 now http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTY2OTg and http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amdnv-phoronix-11&num=5 "Recently, NVIDIA also finally added OpenCL 1.2 support to their proprietary Linux driver." and on Windows as well https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/540773/opencl-1-2-support-in-nvidia-drivers/ "Yes, the latest Win10 drivers from NVIDIA 352.84 & 352.63 include the OpenCL 1.2 support."

Comment: My NVS 5400M (Fermi) appears to run CL 1.2, maybe it was added in later drivers?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 700 series supports OpenCL 1.2

I'm still looking for which driver I'll need to get that working.

Comment: Did you find out if any of their drivers support OpenCL 1.2 ?

Comment: Not yet.  I don't have a lot of hope for this.

Comment: Update from a few years later:  Still no OpenCL 1.2 (or 2.0 or 2.1) but there's some hope on the horizon for Vulcan support.  I'll check back in once that's released with how to do it.

Comment: OK, the GTX 780 series cards with the current drivers as of this date (352.41) supports OpenCL 1.2